# Populate custom Contact fields with last modified Opportunity information

Tags: apex

I have a requirement to populate two **custom fields** on the **Contact** object:

> (Primary_Opportunity_Id__c and Opportunity_Owner_Email__c)

With information from the **most recently modified Opportunity** where that **Contact** is a **primary OpportunityContactRole**.

Here is my current draft of the needed method. This is my first time writing something of this complexity and I would appreciate any insights into areas I am not considering (such as how to build in logic for CRUD):

```
 /*  This method populates the Primary_Opportunity_Id__c and
  *  Opportunity_Owner_Email__c fields on the Contact with matching
  *  information from the most recently modified open Opportunity with 
  */ that Contact as the Primary Contact Role

public static void recalculatePrimaryOpportunity(List<Contact> contacts){      


    // Generate a set of OpportunityContactRoles that match the
    // contacts list and where IsPrimary = true

    Set<OpportunityContactRole> primConRoleSet = new Set<OpportunityContactRole>(
        [SELECT Id, ContactId, OpportunityId 
         FROM OpportunityContactRole 
         WHERE IsPrimary = true and ContactId IN :contacts]);
    system.debug('primConRoleSet size: ' + primConRoleSet.size());  

    //Iterate over primConRoleSet set, populating a map with the 
     OpportunityContactRole (key) and Opportunity__c (value) results

    //Also populate a set of Contact Ids for each Contact associated with the OpportunityContactRole
    Map<Id, Id> conRolesAndOpps = new Map<Id, Id>();
    Set<Id> conWithPrimRoles = new Set<Id>();
    if(primConRoleSet.size()>0){
       for(OpportunityContactRole cr : primConRoleSet){
           conRolesAndOpps.put(cr.Id, cr.OpportunityId);
           conWithPrimRoles.add(cr.ContactId);
        }
    }
    system.debug('conRolesAndOpps size: ' + conRolesAndOpps.size());
    system.debug('conWithPrimRoles size: ' + conWithPrimRoles.size());

    //Then generate a map with a Contact Id (key) and the Id of the most recently modified Opportunity tied to that Contact (value). 
    //Filter by Contacts with a primary OpportunityContact Role
    //Also store the Opportunity Ids in a seperate set
    Map<Id, Id> contactOppMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
    Set<Id> matchingOppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c: 
           [SELECT Id,
           (SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate FROM Opportunities
           WHERE IsClosed != true AND Id IN :conRolesAndOpps.values()
           ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
           FROM Contact
           WHERE Id IN :conWithPrimRoles]){

               for(Opportunity o : c.Opportunities){
                   contactOppMap.put(c.Id, o.Id);
                   matchingOppIds.add(o.Id);
               }    
           }

    //Generate a map of Opportunity Id's (key) and owner emails (value) for Opportunities matched with Contacts above
    Map<Id, String> oppOwnerEmailMap = new Map<Id, String>();
    for(Opportunity o: [SELECT Id, Owner.Email 
                       FROM Opportunity
                       WHERE Id IN :matchingOppIds]){
         oppOwnerEmailMap.put(o.Id, o.Owner.Email);}
    system.debug('oppOwnerEmailMap size: '+ oppOwnerEmailMap.size());

    //Iterate over the initial contacts list and either update the custom fields or, if there is no matching Opportunity, clear them
    List<Contact> conToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    Set<Contact> conEvaluated = new Set<Contact>(); //to prevent iterating over the same contact twice
    for(Contact c : contacts){
        if(!conEvaluated.contains(c)){
            if(contactOppMap.containsKey(c.Id)){ //signifies a matching Opportunity was found
                String primeOpp = contactOppMap.get(c.Id);
                String ownerEmail = oppOwnerEmailMap.get(contactOppMap.get(c.Id));
                if((c.Primary_Opportunity_Id__c != primeOpp) || (c.Opportunity_Owner_Email__c != ownerEmail)){
                    c.Primary_Opportunity_Id__c = primeOpp;
                    c.Opportunity_Owner_Email__c = ownerEmail;
                    conToUpdate.add(c);
                }                
            }else if(!contactOppMap.containsKey(c.Id)){ //signifies there was no matching Opportunity found
                c.Primary_Opportunity_Id__c = '';
                c.Opportunity_Owner_Email__c = '';
                conToUpdate.add(c);
            }                      
            conEvaluated.add(c);
        }
    }
    If(conToUpdate.size()>0){
       system.debug('num contacts to update:' + conToUpdate.size());
       update conToUpdate;
    }
    system.debug('num contacts evaluated: ' + conEvaluated.size());
}
}
```

Comment: Hello J Sinor. What happen if a Contact is primary for more that one or two opportunities in which the two or more opportunities are updated? Have you think about that, or those fields need to be populated by the last opportunity updated?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo - Good question. I could see that happening via data loader. Right now, the procedure would be to grab the first Opportunity that appears in the query and populate the Contact with that. While I don't see this happening often, I will make sure my business users are aware of the consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you are aware of the fact that **you could overwrite field values** because you are **only keeping track of the last most recently update opportunity**, you can do something like this.

We need to build a trigger on the **Opportunity** object. If you are using a trigger handler better, if not.... well... you should :) 
We are going to call a class from our trigger to do the dirty job for us.

```
trigger updateContacFields on Opportunity (after insert, after update){

    // Here we pass our trigger.new to the a helper class to do the work
    ManageContactUpdateForOpportunity.HandleContactsUpdates(trigger.new); 

}
```

The `ManageContactUpdateForOpportunity` class will be something like this:

```
public class ManageContactUpdateForOpportunity{

   //We pass our Opportunities to our method
   public static void HandleContactsUpdates(List<Opportunity> newlist)
   {
    // This map contains opportunities ids and email
    // You could use a set here, I like a map 
    Map<Id, String> oppMap = new Map<Id, String>();   

    Set<Id> primaryCont = new Set<Id>();

    // Using a map here is better than a list, avoid nasty duplication errors
    Map<Id, Contact> conToUpdate = new Map<Id, Contact>();    

    List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id, Owner.Email 
                                   FROM Opportunity
                                       WHERE Id IN: newlist]; 

    // Iteration over the opportunity list
    for(Opportunity o: oppList)
    {
      if(!oppList.isEmpty())
          oppMap.put(o.Id, o.Owner.Email); 
     }

    // Separeting primary contacts from not primary   
    List<OpportunityContactRole> oppConRol =
               [SELECT Id, ContactId, isPrimary, OpportunityId 
                     FROM OpportunityContactRole 
                          WHERE OpportunityId IN: oppMap.keySet() AND isPrimary = true];

    for(OpportunityContactRole ocr1: oppConRol)
    {
        if(!oppConRol.isEmpty())
           primaryCont.add(ocr1.ContactId);        

    }

    // We get a list of contacts with related fields 
    List<Contact> conList =
          [SELECT Id, Primary_Opportunity_Id__c, 
             Opportunity_Owner_Email__c, 
                (SELECT OpportunityId, isPrimary, Opportunity.Owner.Email
                    FROM OpportunityContactRoles 
                       WHERE isPrimary = true) FROM Contact
                          WHERE Id In: primaryCont];

   // Iteration over contacts and assigning values
   for(Contact c: conList)
   {
     for(OpportunityContactRole ocr: c.OpportunityContactRoles)
      {
      if((ocr.isPrimary == true) & (oppMap.containsKey(ocr.OpportunityId)))
          c.Primary_Opportunity_Id__c  = ocr.OpportunityId;
          c.Opportunity_Owner_Email__c = ocr.Opportunity.Owner.Email; 
          conToUpdate.put(c.Id, c);  

     }
     // Updating records.
    }if(conToUpdate.size()>0)
     update conToUpdate.values();
   }
}
```

You can probably use a better structure for the update operation, but this code should work. I tested and:

[image]

Only my primary contact got updated from several opportunity contact roles records on that opportunity.

Comment: Thank you @Carlos! This is very helpful in evaluating the best way to write this code. I will likely keep the method on the ContactTriggerHandler, called by the OpportunityTriggerHandler when certain events fire (and the Opp meets certain criteria).